# Will Tamil localization of .NET application work even if the language is not installed in the target system?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I'm creating a .NET windows forms application. I want to translate it to Tamil. So I use localization property for this. It works fine in my computer. But my doubt is **will this work even if Tamil is not installed in the target computer?**

Comment: Uninstall Tamil localization from your computer and soon you will know the answer.

Comment: @EricLippert I have tried it. It still works :-). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

> Remember that the culture names and identifiers represent only a
>   subset of cultures that can be found on a particular computer. Windows
>   versions or service packs can change the available cultures.
>   Applications add custom cultures using the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder
>   class. Users add their own custom cultures using the Microsoft Locale
>   Builder tool. Microsoft Locale Builder is written in managed code
>   using the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class.

Other than English, you can't be absolutely sure a language will be on the client computer, cultures are specific to the version of windows.  You'll need to either have a fall back language (like english), make the tamil language pack a prerequisite for your application...

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win7

... or alternatively create and deploy your own custom culture with your application.

Comment: Thank you @Mick. learnt a lot form your answer. I'll make Tamil language pack a prerequesite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. Windows has Unicode fonts, so for example, my computer (with russian localization) displays tamil script properly.

Comment: But that's just the fonts. Localization requires a specific CultureInfo.

Comment: @HenkHolterman checked my windows regional settings, tamil is presented here. I'm sure there'll be no problem at all :)

Comment: But what happens when it's not present? That was the question.